# Use Push Notification payload when App launches via the Notification

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications

I was wondering how I can make use of the payload of a push notification, when the user is launching the app via opening that notification. Is this possible?

I want to implement an action which happens upon opening a notification, but this action requires part of the payload to work.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just implement the `application(_ application:, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo:)` in your AppDelegate. The `userInfo` is a JSON representation of your Push Notification (including the Payload).

Additionally you can check if the App is "`inactive`", wich means (in this case), that the User just came in to the App via this Push Notification

Example Code:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any]) {
    if (UIApplication.shared.applicationState == .active) {
        // you just got a PushNotification, but the app is running currently
    } else if (UIApplication.shared.applicationState == .inactive) {
        // Do your work in here, the User just opened the App via the Push Notification
        // check userInfo for the Payload
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer. That helps a lot. The `.active` part works flawlessly. However what I want the App to do when launching from `.inactive` or `.background` doesn't seem to work.